# How to find a specific string followed by a number, with any number of characters between?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex for the following pattern:

> [MyLiteralString][0 or more characters without restriction][at least 1 digit]

I thought this should do it:

```
(theColumnName)[\s\S]*[\d]+
```

As it looks for the literal string `theColumnName`, followed by any number of characters (whitespace or otherwise), and then at least one digit. But this matches more than I want, as you can see here:

https://www.regex101.com/r/HBsst1/1

(EDIT) Second set of more complex data - https://www.regex101.com/r/h7PCv7/1

Using the sample data in that link, I want the regex to identify the two occurrences of `theColumnName] VARCHAR(10)` and nothing more.

I have 300+ sql scripts which containing create statements for every type of database object: procedures, tables, triggers, indexes, functions -- everything. Because of that, I can't be too strict with my regex.

A stored procedure's file might include text like `LEFT(theColumnName, 10)` which I want to identify.

A create table statement would be like `theColumnName VARCHAR(12)`.

So it needs to be very flexible as the number(s) isn't always the same. Sometimes it's 10, sometimes it's 12, sometimes it's 51 -- all kinds of different numbers.

Basically, I'm looking for the regex equivalent of this C# code:

```
//Get file data
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);

//Let's assume the first line contains 'theColumnName'
int theColumnNameIndex = lines[0].IndexOf("theColumnName");

if (theColumnNameIndex >= 0)
{
    //Get the text proceeding 'theColumnName'
    string temp = lines[0].Remove(0, theColumnNameIndex + "theColumnNameIndex".Length;

    //Iterate over our substring
    foreach (char c in temp)
    {
        if (Char.IsDigit(c)) 
            //do a thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(theColumnName).*?[\d]+
```

That'll make it stop capturing after the first number it sees.

The difference between `*` and `*?` is about greediness vs. laziness. `.*\d` for example would match `abcd12ad4` in `abcd12ad4`, whereas `.*?\d` would have its first match as `abcd1`. Check out [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for more info.

Btw, if you **don't** want to match newlines, use a `.` (period) instead of `[\s\S]`